# Prestashop, problema al cargar categorías error 500

Tags: php, html, prestashop

Tengo un problema a la hora de entrar en cualquier categoría de mi pagina web, me da un error 500, he estado mirando pero no he podido solucionarlo, adjunto captura del error concreto por si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias ^^
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: borra el contenido de la carpeta llamada template_c

Comment: Buenas David, perdona que soy novato en esto, intento localizar la carpeta que me comentas pero no consigo encontrarla, normalmente donde está situada?

Comment: Es una carpeta que te genera Smarty, porque entiendo que estas usando Smarty, verdad? En caso de ser afirmativo, en el directorio donde tengas alojada tu pagina web, en el buscador pon templates_c, estará llena de archivos con nombres medio raros y extensión php

Comment: No, no me sale esa carpeta con ese nombre, he probado con otros archivos que creían que podían ser el problema pero me sigue sucediendo

Comment: podrias enseñar las lineas 195 y 385 de smarty_internal_template.php

Comment: Claro, adjunto las capturas

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Usa el boton [edit] y agrega todo la informacion de tu pregunta en la pregunta!!!!

Comment: Buenas David, comprobé la ruta que me pasaste y esos ficheros existen, el caso es estoy viendo que yo tengo problemas con el fichero file:catalog/_partials/category-header.tpl, este fichero no lo he podido encontrar, no existe, sin embargo este otro fichero si 'layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl', ya que el error que me está dando es el siguiente "Unable to load template 'file:catalog/_partials/category-header.tpl' in 'layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl'", si te puedo proporcinar alguna información mas, es la primera vez que me ocurre este problema... y me parece raro, aunq luego seguro que será na

Answer (score -1):

En el archivo layout-both-columns de tu tema estas linkando un archivo que no existe, o al menos no está en la ruta que le estás indicando
Supongo que simplemente eliminando esa linea se solucionaria
Si quieres puedes darme acceso al ftp y te miro de solucionarlo ;)

Comment: Buenas, hay opción de enviarme los datos por mensaje privado?

Comment: Pasame un mail y te contacto..

Comment: Claro, muchas gracias! 94migueltorres@gmail.com